# Printing file but without a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, template

I print labels in sheets using Photoshop CC using a guide. I've been placing what I need on the template and then deleting the template to print, but is there a way to "hide" the template so I don't need to delete it every time?

Here's what I currently do:

- open template .psd
- put items on labels
- delete template gridline layer
- print
- undo delete template gridline layer

I'm hoping to remove the delete/undelete steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just hide the template layer or group and then print the file. Then unhide the layer or group when you want to see and work with the template again.

You can hide the layer or group of layers by clicking on the eye icon next to the layer in the layer panel.

[image: hide layer gif]

Comment: I wasn't sure if hiding the layer also hid it from print jobs. Didn't want to blow a sheet of labels to test it.

Comment: @gator, Yes it does. If the answer worked for you, you may accept it as a solution by clicking on the reserved icon.